# "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly." wcf service

Tags: .net, performance, web-services, wcf, visual-studio-2012

When I try to return a large of data from a wcf service. I get a crash upon returning. The message is "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.".

I have read the hints about this problem; they don't help me. I tried increasing the binding parameters to no avail. I added a trace it didn't give me any useful information.

I find I can return exactly 3274 records without a problem but 3275 is a problem.

I could try paging but that is a last resort.

Here is the key portion of the config file from the Main Program

```
 <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>                 
              <binding name="BasicHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                  openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                  allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                  maxBufferSize="6553600" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600"
                  messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                  useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                  maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                  <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                    realm="" />
                  <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
              </binding>  
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
```

and from the wcf

```
<binding closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
      sendTimeout="00:10:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
```

Comment: How big is a given record?  Can you post your config files?  It could be a case of increasing the limits on the binding but that binding configuration is not actually being used.

Comment: If possible, perhaps you could provide both the client and server configuration snippets for review.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most likely related to either the client or server configuration.  As such, you may want/need to experiment with the readerQuota values.  (for reference, the following represents the max values).

```
<readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
              maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
              maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
```

You may want to enable WCF Tracing on both the client and server and review the logs to help determine the underlying error/cause.

Reference:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The Main Program (client) config file sample above does not appear to use the max values ... <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                  maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"

Comment: I got around the problem by paging. I set a maximum of 3000 returned. I want to try your suggestion when I get a minute.

Comment: OK. I would be interested to know if setting the client's readerQuotas values resolves the issue. Regards.